# Generate dynamic formcontent with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is there some AngularJS shortcut for generating form content with validation?

The number of fields and it's validation rules, type of fields, directives must be loaded from the database in an AngularJS request and be made into fields with all angular stuff.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: I havn't tried anything yet. But I think I would raw-load the angular content if I did.